# Usage of send in a clause

Tags: word-choice, clauses

Which is correct:

1. **"Select a computer where you want us to send your file"**
2. **"Select a computer that you want us to send your file to"**

Is there any less wordy way to express the same thing?

Comment: *Select a computer to which you want your file sent.*

Comment: Grammar aside, files are not sent to computers but to people or organisations at email addresses, Whatsapp numbers or similar that can be accessed on any computer. But if you insist on sending the file to a computer, you could: Select a computer to receive/access your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need shortest form, try something like:
**Select destination computer for your file**
There is no word "send" in this phrase, but this word is implied by the word "destination".